# How to retrieve image from project folder?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make a Java desktop application where I have a `JLabel` where I shuffle images. I am retrieving images from a folder which is on any drive of my PC. Now I want to retrieve all the images from a project folder where the images' folder name is available.

```
 F:/>Kiosk
             |
             |___src
             |
             |___lib
             |
             |___koisk
                   |
                   |__main1.java
             |
             |__images
```

Here is my code
How can i achieve this?

```
public class ImageShuffle1 extends JPanel {

    private List<BufferedImage> list = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
    private List<BufferedImage> shuffled;
    private JLabel label = new JLabel();

    private int width = 700;
    private int height = 700;

    private Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            update();
        }
    });

    public ImageShuffle1() {

        try {
            list.add(resizeImage(ImageIO.read(new File("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\c.jpg"))));
            list.add(resizeImage(ImageIO.read(new File("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\d.jpg"))));
            list.add(resizeImage(ImageIO.read(new File("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\e.jpg"))));
            list.add(resizeImage(ImageIO.read(new File("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\f.jpg"))));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        shuffled = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>(list);
        Collections.shuffle(shuffled);
        timer.start();
    }

    private BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage originalImage) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, width, height, null);
        g.dispose();
        return resizedImage;
    }

    private void update() {
        if (shuffled.isEmpty()) {
            shuffled = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>(list);
            Collections.shuffle(shuffled);
        }

        BufferedImage icon = shuffled.remove(0);
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(icon));
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("ImageShuffle");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.add(label);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ImageShuffle1().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: When programming, you have to think about the way your application should work once installed on an end-user's machine. And end-user won't have your project folder. How do you intend to release your application? Also, if you don't even put your java files in src, what do you put there?

Comment: See also [tag:embedded-resource].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put all the images in `images` folder that you have in your project in parallel to `src` folder.

```
 F:/>Kiosk
             |
             |___src
             |
             |___lib
             |
             |___koisk
                   |
                   |__main1.java
             |
             |__images
                |
                |__c.jpg
                |__d.jpg
                |__e.jpg
                |__f.jpg
```

Use this code

```
list.add(resizeImage(ImageIO.read(new File("images\\c.jpg"))));
list.add(resizeImage(ImageIO.read(new File("images\\d.jpg"))));
list.add(resizeImage(ImageIO.read(new File("images\\e.jpg"))));
list.add(resizeImage(ImageIO.read(new File("images\\f.jpg"))));
```

---

-- EDIT --

You can try any one

```
// Read from same package 
list.add(resizeImage(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("c.png"))));

// Read from absolute path
list.add(resizeImage(ImageIO.read(new File("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\c.png"))));

// Read from images folder parallel to src in your project
list.add(resizeImage(ImageIO.read(new File("images\\c.jpg"))));
```

Repeat any one for all four images.

Comment: How is it possible? Try other options that i have updated in my post.

Comment: *Repeat any one for all four images.* Read inline comments for more information about images location.

Comment: Read *Struts in Action*

Comment: sry i did not get ur mean  can i have your  emailid

Comment: *Struts in Action*. Find on Google. Download PDF or buy a book.