# How to load Images from a package in java

Tags: java

I usually use this to load from the same package

```
Image image;
String img = "image.png";
ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(img));
image = i.getImage();
```

How can I load an image from a package specified for images?

Comment: Well where *is* the image, relative to the class? Please give more context, and it should be pretty easy to help you.

Comment: Find the solution here [How to retrieve image from project folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744920/how-to-retrieve-image-from-project-folderel?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Image image;
String img = "image.png";
ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(img));
image = i.getImage();
```

Suggests that "image.png" resides within the same package as  the class represented by `this`

You can use absolute paths to reference resources that reside within different packages

```
String img = "/path/to/images/image.png";
ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(img));
```

The important concept here is to understand that the path is suffixed to class path

Personally, you should be using `ImageIO` over `ImageIcon`, apart from supporting more formats, it throws an `IOException` when something goes wrong and is guaranteed to return a fully loaded image (when successful).

See [How to read images](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

Answer (score 3):

You can try any one

```
// Read from same package 
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("c.png"));

// Read from absolute path
ImageIO.read(new File("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\c.png"));

// Read from images folder parallel to src in your project
ImageIO.read(new File("images\\c.jpg"));
```

Use

```
ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(<any one from above>);
```

You can use `BufferedImage` also in place of `ImageIcon` directly.

For more information read it here [How to retrieve image from project folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744920/how-to-retrieve-image-from-project-folderel?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Thanks i've seen this before but nobody ever explained it

Comment: What's your project structure?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use(like "this") locally: `this.getClass().getResource( img );`
Just use class loader globally : `ClassLoader.getSystemResource( path );`
I'm gonna show you my library function below

```
public final class PackageResourceLoader {

    // load image icon
    public static final ImageIcon loadImageIcon( final String path ) {

        final URL res = ClassLoader.getSystemResource( path );

        return new ImageIcon( res );
    }


    // load buffered image
    public static final BufferedImage loadBufferedImage( final String path ) {

        final URL res = ClassLoader.getSystemResource( path );

        try { return ImageIO.read( res ); }
        catch( final Exception ex ) { return null; }
    }
}
```

if your `img.png` is in package `pack` use `PackageResourceLoader.loadImageIcon( "pack/img.png" );`