# Java input == null why?

Tags: java, input

I'm using a simple way to get my resources for the project. I'm using Eclipse, and I have a 'res' folder to hold the needed files. This is how I load stuff, for example a 'puppy.png' just in my res folder (no subfolders):

```
String path = "/puppy.png";
try {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(path));
} catch(Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
```

And sometimes I get an input==null error, and sometiomes not! Not like this time puppy.png loaded but next time it won't. For some classes it always loads correctly, and for the other classes I always get this error. Can anyone explain why can this happen, and how can I fix it, but still use the getResourceAsStream() method?

Comment: Try using a backslash instead of a forward slash. It may or may not help.
EDIT: You may not even need the slash at all

Comment: A backslash is not the answer.

Comment: That's why I provided it as a comment rather than an answer. And see my edit, I realized the possibility that I was wrong anyway

Comment: It doesn't, I've tried.

Comment: Maybe you should also print out the classloader of the class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at [How to retrieve image from project folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744920/how-to-retrieve-image-from-project-folder/22746825#22746825).

I have mentioned no of ways to read image from different paths.

You can try any one

```
// Read from same package 
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("c.png"));

// Read from absolute path
ImageIO.read(new File("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\c.png"));

// Read from images folder parallel to src in your project
ImageIO.read(new File("images\\c.jpg"));
```

---

In your case the image must be in the same package where is the class and don't prefix `/`.

Comment: Yes also see the javadoc of the method:
 Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the given resource name using this algorithm:

    If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
    Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:

        modified_package_name/name 

    Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').

Answer (score 0):

Note that if the resource returns null (meaning it doesn't exist), you will get this error.

Check the input returned like so:

```
String path = "/puppy.png";
try {
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
    if (is == null) {
        //resource doesn't exist
    } else {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(is);
    }
} catch(Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
```

Note that you most likely should be using `String path = "puppy.png"`, seeing as you will already be in the content of the project folder.

Comment: How could it be? it does exist!

Comment: If it does not find it, then it will return in that form. Try checking the value returned from `getClass().getResourceAsStream(path)`

Comment: Careful. `getResource` does not expect a file system specific separator. It expects `/` literally.

Comment: Aha, in that case I'll change my answer then.

Comment: However, I didn't down vote, so an explanation would still be nice.

Comment: The main problem is that the resource exists but sometimes cannot be found. This would treat it safely but doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Where is the file in context of your project?