# java how to convert string to icon to do setIcon

Tags: java, string, path

I'm trying to put the String `spath` into `setIcon`.

The path is already save as String, it looks like `C:\Users\Aron\Desktop\220i.jpg`

then i try setIcon by using this string path

```
imagelabel.setIcon(spath)
```

it shows that string cannot convert to icon. what i should do to fix this.

the thing is it need to use the existing path which already stored in the string. what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the image first...

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/Aron/Desktop/220i.jpg"));
```

nb: `ImageIO.read` throws an `IOException`, this is very deliberate, as it provides better management than other image loading methods

You then need to wrap it in an `ImageIcon` class...

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
```

You can then pass it to `setIcon`...

```
imagelabel.setIcon(icon);
```

Take a look at [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) and [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

FYI: `C:/Users/Aron/Desktop/220i.jpg` is only relevant to your current context.  If your move your program to another computer, this image will no longer exists.  You would be better off including the image as an embedded resource within the result application jar or as an image stored relative to your application.

Comment: thanks. but the thing is it need to use the existing path which already stored in the string. what should i do?

Comment: `new File(stringValue)`?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to put the images in the project itself as resources otherwise this code might not work on another system. Try to avoid *absolute path*.

---

You should use `ImageIO` class to load the images that throws exception if image is not found.

You can try any one based on image location.

```
// Read from same package 
Image image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("c.png"));

// Read from images folder parallel to src in your project
Image image = ImageIO.read(new File("images/c.jpg"));

// Read from src/images folder
Image image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/c.png"))

// Read from src/images folder
Image image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/c.png"))
```

Convert Image to ImageIcon:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
```

[Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744920/how-to-retrieve-image-from-project-folder/22746825#22746825)