# How to get the source of an image

Tags: java, image, swing

Here's a simple question: how to get the source of an image. The following are the codes of subclass:

```
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.*;

public class PuzzleGameBoard extends JComponent {

private Image penguin;

public PuzzleGameBoard() {

    penguin = ;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0,  0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    g.drawImage(penguin,  30, 30, this);
}

}
```

I have problem printscreening my java program and my files to be uploaded due to technique limitation. But can anybody teach me the best way of getting the source of an image? Sorry to be not quite specific again..

Comment: where is image file stored?

Comment: *"..can anybody teach me the best way of getting the source of an image?"*  What on Earth are you talking about?  Is this an image that is part of your app. (supplied by you)?  By 'source' DYM 'path'?..

Comment: are you looking for how to show an image.

Comment: myComputer -> F:(myUSB) -> Java -> lab09 -> content -> images -> penguin

Comment: why don't you want to put images in the project itself? The application will not work if your USB is not plugged in.

Comment: Yeah similarly @user3218114

Answer (score 0):

It's worth reading *Java Tutorial* on [Loading Images Using getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html)

---

Just put all the images inside the project itself or bundle all the required resources in a jar and add it in the class-path, then try any one based on image location.

```
// Read from same package 
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("c.png"));

// Read from images folder parallel to src in your project
ImageIO.read(new File("images/c.jpg"));

// Read from src/images folder
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/c.png"))

// Read from src/images folder
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/c.png"))
```

[Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744920/how-to-retrieve-image-from-project-folder/22746825#22746825)

**Note:**  Call `super.paintComponent(g);` at first line in the overridden `paintComponent()` method.